# How to find inside a list element by attribute JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, find

I have this structure

**HTML**

```
<div>
<ul id="categories">
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repeater_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <li><asp:LinkButton ID="linkbutton" runat="server" href="javascript:void(0);"/></li>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        LinkButton linkbutton = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("linkbutton");
        lnkCategoryName.Attributes.Add("data-category", ((ProductCategory)e.Item.DataItem).Description);
    }
}
```

**Inspect element from Developers tool**

```
<ul id="categories">
<li><a id="cphContents_repeater_linkbutton_0" href="javascript:void(0);" data-category="TestValue">Value 1</a></li>
<li><a id= ....
```

What I want is to get the accurate anchor with data-category attribute in Jquery but I cannot do it til now.

I tried this in the console of Developers tool

```
$('#categories > li').children()
```

And it gives me all the anchors elements from all the LI but then I want to choose only the one I'm interested in.

When I do the following line, the console returns the square brackets. Help!!

```
$('#categories > li').children().find('a[data-category=TestValue]')
```

Comment: `$('#categories > li').find('a[data-category="TestValue"]')`

Comment: @juvian, thanks for your answer. Done and nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$('#categories > li').find('a[data-category="TestValue"]')`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/juvian/VDAgS/

Comment: Ok. Sorry I didn't see that you removed the children function. I thought it was about the quotation marks. It works, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check http://jsfiddle.net/yvanavermaet/98K2G/1/

HTML:

```
<ul id="categories">
    <li><a id="cphContents_repeater_linkbutton_0" href="javascript:void(0);" data-category="TestValue">Value 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="cphContents_repeater_linkbutton_1" href="javascript:void(0);">Value 2</a></li>
    <li><a id="cphContents_repeater_linkbutton_2" href="javascript:void(0);">Value 3</a></li>
 </ul>
```

JS:

```
var a = $("#categories > li > a[data-category='TestValue']");
alert(a.length); // this will alert "1"
```